# show message when file upload control does not have any file on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a file upload control on my page and I want to restrict to accept only .csv file and throw message in case any other file is attempted to be uploaded. Moreover, it should throw message when no file is chosen and Upload button is clicked.

**Html** -

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">00</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="field_row">
            <input type="file" accept=".csv" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload1" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="field_row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <center><div class="col-lg-3"><div class="input-append" id="filterDev" style="visibility: hidden">
                        <input name="search" id="inputFilter" placeholder="Enter ID to filter" />
                        <input type="button" value="Filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div></div></center>
                    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
                    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel/Save" style="visibility: hidden" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <input type="button" id="process" value="Process" style="visibility: hidden" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="align-self: center">
                        <div class="panel-body" style=" max-height:600px; min-height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12" id="dvCSV">
                                    <table id="my-table">
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p id="download" style="color: cornflowerblue; visibility: hidden"><strong>Please click the below links to download the processed file..</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <p id="File1" style="color: cornflowerblue; text-decoration: underline; visibility: hidden"><a href="Files/CommitteeMembers.xlsx">File1 Download</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <p id="File2" style="color: cornflowerblue; text-decoration: underline; visibility: hidden"><a href="Files/GSD_Offering_Completion.csv">File2 Download</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#cancel").on("click", function () {
        $('input:checked').each(function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
    });


    $(function () {
        $("#process").bind("click", function () {

            document.getElementById("File1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("File2").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("download").style.visibility = "visible";

        });

    });

    $("#filter").click(function () {
        ids = $("#inputFilter").val();
        if (ids != "") {
            idsArray = ids.split(",");
            $("#my-table tr:gt(0)").hide();
            $.each(idsArray, function (i, v) {
                $("#my-table tr[data-id=" + v + "]").show();
            })
        } else {
            $("#my-table tr").show();
        }
    });


    /*  $("#File1").click(function () {
          window.location = "Files/CommitteeMembers.xlsx";
      });
      $("#File1").click(function () {
          window.location = "Files/GSD_Offering_Completion.xlsx";
      });*/

</script>
```

**Javascript -**

```
$(function () {
    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;

        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    //var table = $("<table id='name'/>");
                    var lines = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    //alert(lines);
                    var result = [];


                    var headers = lines[0].split(",");
                    for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
                        var header = headers[i];
                        header = header.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
                        headers[i] = header;
                    }



                    for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                        var obj = {};
                        var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
                        //alert(currentline);

                        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
                            //alert(obj[headers[j]]);
                        }
                        result.push(obj);
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                    }

                    //alert(result[0].NAME + ' '+ result[0].ADDRESS+" "+result[0].CITY);
                    populateTable(result);
                    document.getElementById("cancel").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("process").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("filterDev").style.visibility = "visible";
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            }

        }

    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#process").bind("click", function () {

        document.getElementById("File1").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("File2").style.visibility = "visible";

    });

});

function populateTable(finalObject) {

    var obj = finalObject;
    var table = $("<table id='my-table' />");
    table[0].border = "1";
    var columns = Object.keys(obj[0]);
    columns.unshift('');
    //alert(columns);
    var columnCount = columns.length;
    var row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));


    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        var headerCell = $("<th />");
        headerCell.html([columns[i]]);
        row.append(headerCell);
    }

    $.each(obj, function (i, obj) {

        row = '<tr data-id="' + obj.ID + '"><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><


    var dvTable = $("#dvCSV");
    dvTable.html("");
    dvTable.append(table);

}
```

How can this be implemented?